# Python sorted() vs .sort() for directory list

Tags: python, sorting, directory

```
file_list = os.listdir(os.getcwd)
files = file_list.sort()
```

If I have a list based on a directory listing as above, why does it sometimes return NoneType if using the files.sort() function but returns intended sort using the sorted(files) function?

Comment: Could you post some of the example directory listings that you are testing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`list.sort()` does an in place sort whereas `sorted(list)` returns a copy of the sorted list. 
This means `.sort()` will return `None` as it has no return, thus defaulting in `None`. Using `sorted()` is usefull if you want to keep the original list, as `.sort()` destroys the original order.

```
>>> my_list = [3, 1, 2]
>>> sorted_list = sorted(my_list)
>>> sorted_list
[1, 2, 3]
>>> my_list
[3, 1, 2]
>>> print my_list.sort()
None
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: i don't quite understand the comment. `sort()` will *always* return `None`

Comment: @conma293 if you definitely want to use `.sort()` just call `file_list.sort()` without assigning it and after the call just operate on `file_list` as it will be sorted

Comment: But if I called files=file_list.sort()  wouldn't that essentially be calling a copy of the sorted in place list and assigning it to files?

Comment: but if I assign a new variable files=file_list.sort() , isn't that the same as the sorted() function?

Comment: @conma293 no, in that case you are assigning `files` to the return value of the function `sort()` on `file_list`. The funtion return `None` so you will assign `files = None`. The best solution for you is to call `files = sorted(file_list)` as this assigns `files` to the return value of the `sorted` function on `file_list`, which returns a copy of the sorted list `files = a_sorted_copy`

Comment: Beautiful that's what I was after! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`list.sort()` is a method of `list` and sorts the list that it is called on in-place and doesn't return anything.

`sorted(collection)` takes any iterable (it can be a list, set, tuple, or even a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)) and returns a list with all the items in sorted order.

Since `sorted(collection)` works any iterable and returns a list it is very useful when chaining method calls or when you can't use `list.sort()`, such as when iterating over the items in a dictionary (which is a tuple):

```
dct = { "c": 1, "b": 3, "a": 7 }
for key, value in sorted(dct.items()):
    print("{} = {}".format(key, value))
```

In your case it doesn't really matter, but I'd go with

```
file_list = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd))
```

purely out of personal preference (it takes up less space).